# WampServer Stop Responding Live Requests after few minutes

Tags: response, wampserver, live

I have setup WampServer with a LIVE IP on WIndows 8, but after few minutes of usage it stop responding to requests, the browser shows connecting progress bar and it goes on.

While on the same machine, when i access the apache server via Localhost, it works fine.

Any quick help to figure out this issue will highly be appreciated. More info can be provided on request.

Comment: Can I ask what version of WAMPServer you are using

Comment: WampServer 2.4
Apache 2.4.4 php5.4.12 ... when we are testing the server from 3/4 different users, then it stops responding, but still work for local requests from the same machine where it is installed

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding these 2 command to your `httpd.conf` file, doing so has fixed similiar issues in the past.

httpd.conf File

Add this section

```
# AcceptFilter: On Windows, none uses accept() rather than AcceptEx() and
# will not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful for network
# adapters with broken driver support, as well as some virtual network
# providers such as vpn drivers, or spam, virus or spyware filters.
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Just before this line ( approx line 480 )

```
# Supplemental configuration
```

It is also worth noting that Windows 8 has a maximum external connection limit, as do all Windows Desktop OS's. The W8 limit is 20 connections, and in  earlier versions the limit is smaller.

Basically if you are trying to run a server i.e. Apache on a desktop OS, it works just great for a single developer situation. It does not however work well under any kind of multi user loading, as Windows Desktop OS's are not configured like a Windows Server. Maybe you should put WAMPServer on a proper Server OS in order to test multi user loads.